# Leaflet Map to static and saving it (as pdf) [R]

Tags: r, pdf, leaflet, maps

How would one convert leaflet map to a static plot and then save it as pdf?,
I have createa a large leaflet map, that has over 150 MB, using `mapshot` does not work because it is very large. I think that convert it to static plot and then save it is more propriate.

I provided example:

```
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

URL2 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_FRA_2_sp.rds"
data2 <- readRDS(url(URL2))


URL3 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_ESP_2_sp.rds"
data3 <- readRDS(url(URL3))

URL4 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_PRT_2_sp.rds"
data4 <- readRDS(url(URL4))

URL5 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_GBR_2_sp.rds"
data5 <- readRDS(url(URL5))

random_long_lat <- 
  data.frame(
    long = sample(runif(300, min = -2.5, max = 15.99), replace = F),
    lat = sample(runif(300, min = 42.69, max = 59.75), replace = F)
  )

all <- rbind(data2, data3, data4, data5)
all@data <- 
  all@data %>% 
  mutate(counts = rnorm(nrow(all), 100, sd = 20))

cuts <- c(0, 5, 20, 40, 80, 150, max(all@data$counts))
cuts <- colorBin("Greens", domain = all$counts, bins = cuts)

m <- 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addPolygons(data=all, stroke = TRUE, color = "white", weight="", smoothFactor = 0.95, 
              fillOpacity = 0.65, fillColor = ~cuts(all$counts)) %>% 
  addLegend(pal = cuts, 
            values = all$counts,
            labFormat = labelFormat(suffix = " "),
            opacity = 0.85, title = "How many point were counted in each region", position = "topright")
```

I would like to convert map `m` to static map, and then save it as pdf, however I can quite figure out how.

Using command for example:

```
library(mapview)
mapshot(m, file = "maps.pdf")
```

Is very slow and when saving map that has more than 100MB usually returns an error.

Comment: take a look at the `webshot`-package.. it support saven a leaflet-screenshot as pdf.. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/webshot/versions/0.5.2/topics/webshot  procesS: first save leaflet to html-file using `htmltools::savewidget()`, and then use `webshot` to make e screenhsot of the saved html-file..

Comment: and `mapview::mapshot()` can do the above without saveing the leaflet-object first...

Comment: As I mentioned both these approaches are very slow and usually do not finish and return an error

Comment: I've successfully used the [**chromote**](https://github.com/rstudio/chromote) package. It has instructions how to take a screenshot in the `README`. This may work better as there is no need to create a stand-alone `.html`. It will, however, only get you half way, as I don't think it supports saving to `.pdf` directly. You'd need to convert yourself afterwards, probably using pandoc or `library(magick)`.

Comment: @TimSalabim  thank you, can you please present your idea as an answer.